# How to weight loss in regression

Tags: machine-learning, regression, class-imbalance, weighted-data

I've got a regression problem where a model is required to predict a value in the range [0, 1].

I've tried to look at the distribution of the data and and it seems that there are more examples with a low value label ([0, 0.2]) than higher value labels ([0.2, 1]).

When I try to train the model using the MAE metric, the model converges to a state where it has a very low loss, but it seems that the model has converged to a state in which it predicts a low value on many of the high value label examples.

So my assumption was that the data is imbalanced and I should try to weight the loss of the examples depending on their label.

**Question:** what is the best way to weight the loss in this configuration?

Should I weight each example by the value of its label using some function f(x) , where f(x) is low when x is low and high when x is high?

*Or* should I split the label values into bins ([0, 0.1), [0.1, 0.2) ... [0.9, 1]) and weight each bin (similarly to categorical loss weight)?

Comment: Do not do it without any statistical look. You can use Pandas' df.describe() to statistically visualize the distribution of your features and labels, then you can actually see what is the mean, variance, min value, max values etc. Then you can decide how to weigh them numerically, and I'd go for weighing the bins as you described at the end.

Comment: I'd like to ask a few questions regarding you response :)   
1. Can you supply some intuition regarding why would you prefer to weigh as bins? I'd love to understand that better 2. What more information would you look for, and how would it influence your weighing? 3. If you suggest to weigh them as bins, than it is the same as categorical weighting. As far as i know in this case you could just weigh them according to the distribution of the bins, Do you agree? if you do, than how would any more statistical information help? :)

Comment: 1) Because it is usually more safe and efficient to use categorical features, rather than numerical. The memory it takes decreases, the algorithms you use will have a speed boost in training (you can use one-hot-encoding to make your dataset even sparser) and categorical features allow us to use the magic of the feature engineering better, in general. 2) I used the word 'safe' at the first sentence; outliers are the danger. If you do not at least statistically manipulate your numerical features, you may end up with strong outliers and with a function f(x), you would reinforce them.

Comment: 2) (Continued) You can look for the most of the data where your samples fell to, 90% is the rule-of-thumb in general. Let's say 90% of your features are in [0.05, 0.2], the remaining 10% are in the intervals [0, 0.05] and [0.2, 1]. Those remaining samples are the outliers and they could strongly harm your cost (sum of losses) in the training, since they will have large errors yet with a few samples to trust in. My advice is: discretize your values in [0.05, 0.2] as some number of bins, and merge the remaining samples to the bins of [0.05, a] or [b, 0.2] depending on the side.

Comment: 3)Yes, it is categorical weighting, and yes you can do that, much easily and safer. I agree with you, I think I gave some extra statistical answer at the answer of your question 2. . Hope I could help; if not, do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Firstly, Thank you very much for all your explanations! And i'd love some elaboration on the manipulation of the data. Let's say the majority of the data is spread across the range [0,0.2] (more than 90% of the data) and the rest is in the range (0.2,1]. If i'm only interested in knowing if the label would be low ( [0,0.2] ) or high ( [0.2, 1] ) than i could categorize the data into 2 bins - low and high. If i do care about finer categorization in the high label range, than instead of merging the data as you suggested I guess I could split the higher values into more bins.

Comment: But ultimately it seems that you suggest i would approach this problem in a categorical manner rather than in a regression manner. Does the categorical approach has a higher probability to result in better performance than the regression approach? If so, why is that? is it because we can basically look at the fewer, higher value examples as outliers and beause regression cant handle outliers?

Comment: And finally, Is there someway to manipulate the data so that i could still use the regression approach? If it is possible to receive higher label resolution, i'd love to do that :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85872/discussion-between-gal-avineri-and-ugur-muluk).

Answer (score 1):

If you are predicting values between 0 and 1, you should use beta regression.

Beta regression will handle the heteroskedasticity or skewness which are commonly observed in rates or proportions.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior seems completely reasonable to me and raises no red flags.

You know that most of the values are small. Consequently, the likelihood of getting a large value is small, even when you consider the features.

Your predictions align with this: predictions tend to be small, as I would argue they should be.

There might be room for improvement. One answer mentions beta regression, which could be an option to explore. If your values are bounded between zero and one because they are proportions of times events happened, [you can consider obtaining the original counts and modeling the discrete outcomes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/594957/247274).

The key point, however, is that this model seems to be doing what it should be doing.